# Update working on target repo when changes are pushed to it

Tags: git

I'm implementing GIT for web developemnt, and I want to have the working copy repository that everybody pushes to automatically reflect the latest commit in it (since it is online for everyone on the team to see as a testing site). Right now, you have to run "git reset --hard HEAD" on the repository after somebody pushes to it in order to be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you generally [don't push to a non-bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean), precisely because you can end up too easily with an incoherent state between the working directory and the index.

```
warning: updating the currently checked out branch; this may cause confusion,
as the index and working tree do not reflect changes that are now in HEAD.
```

But since in your case, you want to take advantage of an existing "live" repo, you could setup a **[post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)**.

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_DIR=
cd ..
echo "Resetting working tree..."
git reset --hard
echo "Finished resetting working tree."
```

, as suggested by [Frerich Raabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91757/frerich-raabe) in "[Git: Post-update hook that runs a script that needs access to all files in the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558036/git-post-update-hook-that-runs-a-script-that-needs-access-to-all-files-in-the-re)"